# Add Carousel View inside Textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, icarousel, nstextattachment

I am adding data into `TextView` through `sqlite database`. I have around 30 to 35 images to be added in it after some Para or Line of data, which i have done through `NSTextAttachment`. Now what i want to do is wherever there are more that 2 images i want it to be in `Carousel View` and remaining data after it. Have a look at my code. I tried the different way but not getting success. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment1 = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    textAttachment1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
    NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"];
    NSTextAttachment *textAttachment2 = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    textAttachment2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"];
    NSTextAttachment *textAttachment3 = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];

    CGFloat oldWidth1 = textAttachment1.image.size.width;
    CGFloat oldWidth = textAttachment.image.size.width;
    CGFloat oldWidth2 = textAttachment2.image.size.width;

    CGFloat scaleFactor1 = oldWidth1 / (self.textViewResearch.frame.size.width + 70);
    CGFloat scaleFactor = oldWidth / (self.textViewResearch.frame.size.width + 70);
    CGFloat scaleFactor2 = oldWidth2 / (self.textViewResearch.frame.size.width + 70);

    textAttachment1.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:textAttachment1.image.CGImage scale:scaleFactor1 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:textAttachment.image.CGImage scale:scaleFactor orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    textAttachment2.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:textAttachment2.image.CGImage scale:scaleFactor2 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage1 = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment1];
    NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
    NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage2 = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment2];

    [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage1];
    [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(13740, 0) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
    [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(13741, 0) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage2];

     self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: What about use uicollectionview instead? Put your first two images in the first cell, which are contained in a uicollectionviewcell. Then leave the rest as common cells. I  wonder if I get your idea right...

Comment: not possible @Calios. The app is different i cant add UIColllectionVIew

Comment: *I tried the different way but not getting success.* What exactly want wrong?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad i want images in the textview to slide horizontally not vertically. So wanted to add carousel in textView where i am not able do so!

Comment: The carousel shall be a subview of the textview?

Comment: I have tried different ways but no success. I have posted the code in my question. You can use it and try for the solution

Comment: I'd create a special UITextView, not use NSTextAttachment, use NSTextContainer or something like that to know where to insert the UICollectionView and where to continue the text (after the UICollectionView). It's quite a lot of work, but you shouldn't be able to do it with NSTextAttachment. Or if Yes, you may detect the selection of a NSTextAttachment (delegate method of UITextView), enumerate the attribute string to resize the other items, but clearly, I don't think that you would have the wanted result.

Comment: I would try using [Pen](https://github.com/jasonsilberman/Pen). It's a tool I made exactly to do this. It uses NSTextAttachment under the hood, but then allows you to have views that you can interact with inside the UITextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to place an image inside a text view and let the text flow around it. Having more than 2 images you want to have a carousel, an instance of the class `iCarousel`.

Having a subview inside an instance of `UITextView` and letting the text float around it, is a known tasks. The easiest way seems to be to use the exclusion path of a text container like this:

```
// Get the dimension of the subview
iCarousel *subview = …; 
UIBezierPath *subviewPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:subview.frame];

// Somewhere you should add it 
UITextView *textView = …; // Wherever it comes from
[textView addSubview:subview];

// Let the text flow around it
UITextContainer *textContainer = textView.textContainer; // The text container is the region text is laid out in. 
textContainer.exclusionPaths = [subviewPath]; // Do not lay out in this region.
```

Of course you have to change the exclusion region, whenever the frame of the subviews change.

A more flexible and more complex approach is to do the text layout your own. If the above approach does not work, let me know. I will add code for this.

Comment: Thanx for your contribution Amin, the above code doesn't work and what i figured out is , it is not possible to add carousel view inside texview. Other solution suggested by my friend is Using a TableView with custom cell. Let's see as i am implementing the solution. Once i am done with it i ll surely inform you.

Comment: I never put a carousel view into a text view. But it is definitely possible to put a view into a text view and I do not see any reason, why a carousel view should not work there.

Comment: Hi Amin thanx  a lot for your help, i haven't implemented it yet, but i have found the solution through tableview which i found it easy, Still your solution is a valid one. So the bounty belongs to you. :)